# how to grep multiple lines until ; (semicolon)

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I'd like to grep lines starting with `printf`, however it could not end at that line and it can have more lines with `\` (backslash).
For instance,

```
printf("%s %s %s", \
        "one more line", \
        "second one", \
        "third one");
```

Yes, we can use the option `-A` (After) but it could include also meaningless lines as it specifies the number how many lines shall be output.

Please let me know if you have a brilliant idea to solve.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a way to do it with grep.

If you allow tools such as perl, there are more options:

```
perl -ne 'print if /^printf/ .. /;/' input.txt
```

If a line starting with `printf` is found, it will be printed along with all following lines until a `;` is found.

Or:

```
perl -ne 'print if /^printf/ .. !/\\$/' input.txt
```

Same logic, but the stop condition is a line not ending with `\`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have an another, additional question. What if I want to print out its filename and linenumber in the form of quickfix(<a full path of filename>:<linenumber> like as grep does with the options -nH??

Comment: @windrg00 Untested, but should be possible with `perl -ne 'print "$ARGV:$.: $_" if /^printf/ .. !/\\$/ } continue { close ARGV if eof ' ...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
foo
printf("%s %s %s", \
        "one more line", \
        "second one", \
        "third one");
bar
$
$ awk '/printf/{f=1} f; !/\\$/{f=0}' file
printf("%s %s %s", \
        "one more line", \
        "second one", \
        "third one");
$
```