# How to grep multi line string with new line characters or tab characters or spaces

Tags: linux, shell, perl, grep

My test file has text like:

```
> cat test.txt
new dummy("test1", random1).foo("bar1");
new dummy("
        test2", random2);
new dummy("test3", random3).foo("bar3");
new dummy = dummy(
            "test4", random4).foo("bar4");
```

I am trying to match all single lines ending with semicolon (;) and having text "dummy(". Then I need to extract the string present in the double quotes inside dummy. I have come up with the following command, but it matches only the first and third statement.

```
> perl -ne 'print if /dummy/ .. /;/' test.txt | grep -oP 'dummy\((.|\n)*,'
dummy("test1",
dummy("test3",
```

With -o flag I expected to extract string between the double quotes inside dummy. But that is also not working. Can you please give me an idea on how to proceed?

Expected output is:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
```

Some of the below answers work for basic file structures. If lines contains more than 1 new line characters, then code breaks. e.g. Input text files with more new line characters:

```
new dummy("test1", random1).foo("bar1");
new dummy("
        test2", random2);
new dummy("test3", random3).foo("bar3");
new dummy = dummy(
            "test4", random4).foo("bar4");
new dummy("test5",
        random5).foo("bar5");
new dummy("test6", random6).foo(
        "bar6");
new dummy("test7", random7).foo("
        bar7");
```

I referred to following SO links:

[How to give a pattern for new line in grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652568/how-to-give-a-pattern-for-new-line-in-grep)

[how to grep multiple lines until ; (semicolon)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45921290/how-to-grep-multiple-lines-until-semicolon)

Comment: `perl -0777 -nle 'print for /dummy\("([^"]*)"/g' test.txt`

Comment: For irregular quoted fields, you might like to have a look at `quotewords` from the core module [`Text::ParseWords`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text::ParseWords).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@TLP was pretty close:

```sh
perl -0777 -nE 'say for map {s/^\s+|\s+$//gr} /\bdummy\(\s*"(.+?)"/gs' test.txt
```

```
test1
test2
```

Using

- `-0777` to slurp the file in as a single string
- `/\bdummy\(\s*"(.+?)"/gs` finds all the quoted string content after "dummy(" (with optional whitespace before the opening quote)

  - the `s` flag allows `.` to match newlines.
  - any string containing escaped double quotes will break this regex
- `map {s/^\s+|\s+$//gr}` trims leading/trailing whitespace from each string.

Comment: Thank you so much! It almost works. :) When value to be extracted including the double quotes is on new line, it doesn't work. I have updated my question with the scenario of "test4". How can we match this additional scenario?

Answer (score 3):

This `perl` should work:

```sh
perl -0777 -pe 's/(?m)^[^(]* dummy\(\s*"\s*([^"]+).*/$1/g' file

test1
test2
test3
test4
```

Following `gnu-grep + tr` should also work:

```sh
grep -zoP '[^(]* dummy\(\s*"\s*\K[^"]+"' file | tr '"' '\n'

test1
test2
test3
test4
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code, written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)new[^;]*;' '
RT{
  rt=RT
  gsub(/\n+|[[:space:]]+/,"",rt)
  match(rt,/"[^"]*"/)
  print substr(rt,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ cat file
new dummy("test1", random1).foo("bar1");
new dummy("
        test2", random2);
new dummy("test3", random3).foo("bar3");
new dummy = dummy(
            "test4", random4).foo("bar4");
```

You can use GNU grep this way:

```
$ grep -ozP '[^;]*\bdummy[^";]*"\s*\K[^";]*[^;]*;' file | tr '\000' '\n' | grep -oP '^[^"]*'
test1
test2
test3
test4
```

Somewhat more robust, if this is a `;` delimited text, you can:

1. split on the `;`;
2. filter for `/\bdummy\b/`;
3. grab the first field in quotes;
4. strip the whitespace.

Here is all that in a `ruby`:

```
ruby -e 'puts $<.read.split(/(?<=;)/).
                select{|b| b[/\bdummy\b/]}.
                map{|s| s[/(?<=")[^"]*/].strip}' file 
# same output
```

Comment: Thank you @dawg. This breaks if "randomx" strings are on the new line. e.g. you can try adding a new character before random1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Text::ParseWords`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text::ParseWords) to extract the quoted fields.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::ParseWords;

my $str = do {
    local $/;
    <DATA>;
};   # slurp the text into a variable
my @lines = quotewords(q("), 1, $str);   # extract fields
my @txt;

for (0 .. $#lines) {
    if ($lines[$_] =~ /\bdummy\s*\(/) {
        push @txt, $lines[$_+1];         # target text will be in fields following "dummy("
    }
}

s/^\s+|\s+$//g for @txt;     # trim leading/trailing whitespace
print Dumper \@txt;

__DATA__
new dummy("test1", random1).foo("bar1");
new dummy("
        test2", random2);
new dummy("test3", random3).foo("bar3");
new dummy = dummy(
            "test4", random4).foo("bar4");
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'test1',
          'test2',
          'test3',
          'test4'
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk`-based solution handling everything via `FS` :

```
<test1.txt gawk -b -e 'BEGIN { RS="^$"

 FS="((^|\\n)?"(___="[^\\n")"]+y[(]"(_="[ \\t\\n]*")(__="[\\42]")(_)\
    "|"(_="[ \\t]*")(__)(_)"[,]"(___)";]+[;][\\n])+"} sub(OFS=ORS,"",$!--NF)'          

test1
test2
test3
test4
```

`gawk` was benchmarked at  `2 million rows` at `5.15 secs`, so unless your input file is beyond `100 MB`, this suffices.

*** caveat : avoid using `mawk-1.9.9.6` with this solution

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting simple `gawk` script (standard linux `awk`):

```
 awk '/dummy/{print gensub("[[:space:]]*","",1,$2)}' RS=';' FS='"'  input.txt
```

#### Explanation:

`RS=';'`  Set `awk` records separator to `;`

`FS='"'`  Set `awk` fields separator to `"`

`/dummy/`  Filter only records matching`dummy` RexExp

`gensub("[[:space:]]*","",1,$2)` Trim any white-spaces from the beginning of 2nd field

`print gensub("[[:space:]]*","",1,$2)` print trimmed 2nd field